# Key error when working with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, keyerror

I get an error when trying to access a single or multiple elements in a pandas dataframe this way data["temp"]. Here is a code snippet on how I am loading the data:

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("weather_data.csv")

y = data["temp"]
print(y)
```

The csv file -> :

> day;temp;condition
> Monday;12;Sunny
> Tuesday ;14;Rain
> Wednesday;15;Rain
> Tuesday ;14;Cloudy
> Friday;21;Sunny
> Saturday;22;Sunny
> Sunday;24;Sunny

Here is the error I am getting:

```
line 3790, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "index.pyx", line 181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'temp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:NAME", line 5, in <module>
    y = data["temp"]
  File "C:\Users\sehab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3893, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\sehab\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3797, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'temp'
```

is the problem with my code or with the package of pandas ?

Comment: What does `data.columns` return?

Comment: You don't have column `'temp'`. Post the relevant part of the csv file.

Comment: @BigBen it returns : ''' Index(['day;temp;condition'], dtype='object') '''

Comment: `data = pandas.read_csv("weather_data.csv", sep=";")`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question includes a pandas dataframe, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not parsing your csv correctly since the default separator is `","` but you have `";"` instead.

Try the following:

```
data = pandas.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer="weather_data.csv",
    sep=";",
    header=0
)
```

Comment: @BigBen good point! Voting now...